# How to get consumer key instead of full website HTML

Tags: magento2, token

I am very new to Magento and I have installed it on localhost. I have an integration which provided my a consumer key/secret. I was trying to get a consumer token in postman. What I am getting is the entire wesite in html and not the tokens I am using the "`/V1/integration/customer/token`"end point via PostMan. I tried using with a plain username/password, but I still get the full website (I have set to receive application/json).The response code is 200 Ok means it's doing the right thing. Can someone please guide me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There was problem creating the username/password. I used the default roni_cost@example.com and I got the token back correctly.